# Hash multiple files

Tags: c++

I'm trying to hash multiple files, but there is an error.

My files name start from Cheque 08365**4**.tif - 08365**122**.tif

My code:

```
    for (int i = 4; i < 123; i++)
    {
        stringstream file;
        file<< "C:/Users/user/Desktop/datasets/Cheque 08365" << i << ".tif";
        string filename = file.str();
        cout << filename << '\n';   

        unsigned char *sha256digest = calculateSHA256(filename);

        char *sha256hash = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 65);
        sha256hash[65] = '\0';

        for (int i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            sprintf(&sha256hash[i * 2], "%02x", sha256digest[i]);
        }

        printf("SHA256 HASH: %s\n", sha256hash);

        system("pause");
        
    }
```

The error states that **no suitable conversion function from string to char * exists** at the *filename* in:

```
unsigned char *sha256digest = calculateSHA256(filename);
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try `unsigned char *sha256digest = calculateSHA256(filename.c_str());` or `unsigned char *sha256digest = calculateSHA256(filename.data());`

Comment: Why `malloc` 65 chars instead of `SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH`? Why use `malloc` at all? Also, you `malloc` _after_ you've already calculated the result. What's the signature of that `calculateSHA256` function? What library are you using to do the calculation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your answer. I've tried both of your suggestions, but the error states that: argument of type const char * is incompatible with parameter type of char *

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for replying. The library that I used is OpenSSL. About the malloc, yes I suppose to use SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH. I forgot to change it. I'm sorry but I'm new to OpenSSL library, so mostly my coding is based on references, and I saw someone used malloc, I thought that I suppose to use it. Should I not use malloc after the calculation? But there is another malloc, which is before calculating the result.

Comment: @C-Na Hmm, that's strange. It was the reason I was suggesting to use `filename.data()` which should have a [return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) of `char *`, unless you're compiling with the c++ 20 standard. Can you post the exact verbatim error message please, to assure that it's `filename` causing the error, and not the return type of `calculateSHA256()`.

Comment: I don't recognize `calculateSHA256()` from OpenSSL. Did you create it?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The exact error is, 'unsigned char *calculateSHA256(char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char*' to 'char *'

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. Inside the calculateSHA256() is where the OpenSSL being implemented.

Comment: @C-Na So `calculateSHA256(filename.data());` should work compiled with `--std=c++-17` compiler flag. Ensure in your project settings, that the latter is true.

Comment: @C-Na Didn't any of the answers help you? I just realized that this question is still open. If you need clarification from any of us who answered, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

If `calculateSHA256` returns `std::string`, that assignment is illegal in more ways than one. `char *` is just a pointer to that storage, string returned by function is a temporal object, which stops existing after semicolon. First, you have to save that string, second, to access its data  by appropriate member function. There is no  way to convert string directly to a pointer.

Or don't use pointer at all. You would find it better to avoid using C idioms at all.

```
    std::string sha256digest = calculateSHA256(filename);

    // FORMATTED OUTPUT
    std::stringstream hashstr;
    hashstr << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for( auto x : sha256digest )   // this would iterate through entirety of string
    {
        hashstr << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(x));
    }

    std::string output;
    hashstr >> output;
    std::cout << "SHA256 HASH: " << output;
```

Comment: I think values <= `0xF` (including negative values) may cause the output to be ugly. Perhaps this will be better: `hashstr << std::setfill('0');` and then in the loop: `hashstr << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(x));`

Comment: @TedLyngmo true, working from phone. tested and added. Technically  std::hex should take care of sign-ness

Comment: Without the cast to `unsigned char` you'd end up with `ffffffff` instead of `ff` for -1, but it's looking good now. +1

Comment: @TedLyngmo is string hold signed chars, I get it. THat doesn't expose itself in test environment because string implemented using unsigned, but that's fair point. Similar flaw the ``+x` would expose, but in that case it would even if  x was unsigned.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to implement it into my coding.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `stringstream` to construct the filename. Use `std::to_sting()`.

I think most of the simplification can be done inside your own `calculateSHA256()` function. Let it return a `std::vector` or `std::string` instead of a `char*`.

Here's an example where I let it return a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` instead:

```cpp
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// An EVP_MD_CTX helper class
class EvpMdCtx {
public:
    explicit EvpMdCtx(const EVP_MD* type, ENGINE* impl = nullptr) : EvpMdCtx() {
        if(init(type, impl) == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("EVP_DigestInit_ex failed");
    }

    EvpMdCtx() : ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_new()) {
        if(ctx == nullptr) throw std::runtime_error("EVP_MD_CTX_new failed");
    }

    EvpMdCtx(const EvpMdCtx&) = delete;
    EvpMdCtx& operator=(const EvpMdCtx&) = delete;

    ~EvpMdCtx() { EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx); }

    int init(const EVP_MD* type, ENGINE* impl = nullptr) {
        return EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, type, impl);
    }

    int update(const void* d, size_t cnt) { return EVP_DigestUpdate(ctx, d, cnt); }

    auto finalize() {
        std::vector<std::uint8_t> md_value(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE);
        unsigned md_len;

        if(EVP_DigestFinal_ex(ctx, md_value.data(), &md_len) == 0)
            md_value.clear();
        else
            md_value.resize(md_len);

        return md_value;
    }

private:
    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx;
};

std::vector<std::uint8_t> calculateSHA256(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream is(filename);
    if(not is) return {};

    EvpMdCtx ctx(EVP_sha256());

    char buf[BUFSIZ]; // a buffer to fill

    while(true) {
        is.read(buf, std::size(buf));
        auto len = is.gcount();
        if(len > 0) {
            if(ctx.update(buf, static_cast<size_t>(len)) == 0) return {};
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    // finalize
    return ctx.finalize();
}

int main() {
    const std::string file = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/datasets/Cheque 08365";

    for(int i = 4; i <= 122; ++i) {
        std::string filename = file + std::to_string(i) + ".tif";
        auto res = calculateSHA256(filename);

        if(res.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Failed: " << filename << '\n';

        } else {
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
            for(auto v : res) {
                std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(v);
            }
            std::cout << ' ' << filename << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```